# Validate special chars JavaScript

Tags: javascript, validation, special-characters

I have the following JS code:

**Edit**

```
      function validateForm() {
            var IsOk = true;
            var RegNumbers = (/^[0-9]+$/);
           var iChars = "!@#$%^&*()+=-[]\';,/{}|\":<>?";
           if (Fname == null || Fname == "") {
                    alert("can't be empty");
                    IsOk = false;
                }
                else if (Fname.length < 2) {
                    alert("the iput too short ");
                    IsOk = false;
                }
  else if (Fname != "") {

            if (RegNumbers.test(Fname)) {
                alert("Fname can't include numbers");
                IsOk = false;
            }
                    for (var i=0; i<Fname.length;) {
                 if (iChars.indexOf(Fname[i]) != -1) {
                    IsOk = false; alert('no special chracters pleas!');

                     break;
                 }

    }

    }
            }
```

The problem is that when the input is special characters there is no alert that it is not allowd. why??
Wish for help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This line :

```
if (iChars.indexOf(Fname) >= 0) {
```

is only testing if the `Fname` string is inside `iChars`. Except rare cases, you're only testing if `Fname` is a one char string containing a special char.

To keep the same logic (that is not use a regex), you would have to iterate over Fname :

```
for (var i=0; i<Fname.length; i++) {
   if (iChars.indexOf(Fname[i]) >= 0) {
      alert('...');
      IsOk = false;
      break;
   }
}
```

You could "simplify" using a regex :

```
if (Fname.match(/[\!\@#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\+\=\-\[\]\\\'\;\,\/\{\}\|\"\:\<\>\?]/)) {
      alert('...');
      IsOk = false;
}
```

Comment: Thnak you for your answer, but how can I fix it (I just startd learning JS..)

Comment: Hi, there is a problemwith your solution. If the input is ok, the page is stuck. why?

Comment: @NaveTseva I forgot a `i++` in the first solution. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to test any one of the characters, your best way is with a regex:

```
var iChars = "!@#$%^&*()+=-[]\';,/{}|\":<>?";
  ,    iRx = new RegExp( '[\\' + iChars.split('').join( '\\' ) + ']' );

...

if( iRx.test( Fname ) ) {
    ...
}
```

What this does is turns your list of special characters into a regular expression:

```
[\!\@\#...]
```

meaning if any of those characters is anywhere in your string it will match

Any FYI, you don't need the `==null` check.  It's functionally the same as `==""`.  Nor do you need the `!= ""` check (as you've already checked that)

And your numbers regex should just be `/[0-9]/`, otherwise `foo22bar` would be allowed.